# Facebook Graph API Photo Upload Image ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api

brand new here.. I've looked everywhere, couldn't find an answer.. :/  Hopefully someone here can help me out.  I'm using the graph api to upload a photo, and tag the user in it.  This is currently working great.  I would like to show the user the image, in the album, so I need the image id to generate the url.  I cannot figure out how to do this!! Below are the lines of code that upload/tag the photo, to my app's album.  What do I need to do to get this image id?  Thanks a lot!  -Tim

> $user = $facebook->getUser(); 
>   function post_image($facebook, $user,
>   $image_path){
>       try{       $tag = array(
>               'tag_uid' => $facebook->getUser(),
>               'x' => 0,
>               'y' => 0
>           );
>           $tags[] = $tag;
>
> ```
>     $image = array(
> 'message'=> 'Your Banner Photo',  'tags' => $tags,
>
>     );
>     $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
>     $image['image'] = '@'.realpath($image_path);
>     $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $image);
>     echo "";
>     return true;
> }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
>     echo $e;
>     return false;
> } }
> ```

Comment: Here is the actual call to the function...

$image_path = 'uploaded_files/t5'.$fname;
$image_uploaded = post_image($facebook, $user, $image_path);

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you have to do it as a separate query. You have to get the users galleries (first graph API call). then find the gallery ID you want and request the photos (second graph API call) then parse through the photos to find the one you want. Finally you have to request that photo.

**-------------------Update:---------------------------**

I'm not a very proficient php developer, but i use facebook api all the time with javascript or actionscript. The basic premise is to call the graph api, and it will return a json object of the result. Use getFile or Curl to load the graph api responses.

You can test your graph api calls here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=663032752

so try and walk that through from the graph api. Get the user galleries, then get the photos, then get the one you want.

To get the albums, call

"https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token="._accessToken;

To get the photos in an album you call it using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/"._albumID."/photos?access_token="._accessToken;
```

And then to get the individual photo you would get the photo's ID property and call that.
sometihng like:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/".your_photo_id;
```

I think using CURL is a good approach, but I'm weak on php, so use what you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You have the photo ID in facebook API response, if it is uploaded successfully:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $image);
echo $result['id'];
```